# numpy array with cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to port some python code to cython and I'm encountering some minor problems.

Below you see a code snippet (simplified example) of the code.

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def Interpolation(cells, int nmbcellsx):
    cdef np.ndarray[float,ndim=1] celle
    cdef int cellnonzero
    cdef int i,l
    for i in range(nmbcellsx):
          celle = cells[i].e
          cellnonzero = cells[i].nonzero
          for l in range(cellnonzero):
               celle[l] = celle[l] * celle[l]
```

I don't understand why the inner-most loop does not fully translate to C code (i.e. the last line, celle[l] = ...), see output from `cython -a feedback`:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That image is a bit hard to read - Copy and paste of the relevant bit would be easier...

Comment: What c compiler do you have ?  Is `celle[l] *= celle[l]` the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realized that a simple "return 0" at the very end of the function solves this problem. However, this behaviour seems quite strange to me. Is this actually a bug?